# jQuery positioning: position({ my: "", at: "", OF: VARIABLE })

Tags: jquery, css, position, css-position

Heyey, I have this function:

```
GravityCircle.position = function(idcontainer){

    var parent = $('.'+idcontainer+' .border');

    $('.'+idcontainer+' .info').position({
                                my: 'center center',
                                at: 'center center',
                                of: 'parent'});
};
```

What I want is to set the object I have in `var parent` inside the `position({ of: ""})`

I've also tried this: `of: '.'+idcontainer+' .border'`

this: `of: "'.'+idcontainer+' .border'"` (also reverting the colons and semicolons)

and this: `of: "$('.'+idcontainer+' .border')"` , but I can't get it to work.

Of course I have the UI plugin installed, and everything is fine because if I use a simple selector like `of: ".border"` it works (not my way, but works).

**Extra**

*HTML*

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="container3"></div>

    <script other scripts></script>
    <script>
        var data ={"value": 2.5,"color": "green","title": "Risque bas"};
        var data2 ={"value": 15445.6460,"color": "red","title": "Risque haut"};
        var data3 ={"value": 8,"color": "orange","title": "Risque moyen"};
        GravityCircle.createGravityCircle("container", data);
        GravityCircle.createGravityCircle("container2", data2);
        GravityCircle.createGravityCircle("container3", data3);
    </script>
</body>
```

*more JS*

```
GravityCircle.createGravityCircle = function (idcontainer, jsonProgressBar) {
    var objJSON = jsonProgressBar;
    try {
        objJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonProgressBar);
    } catch (error) {}
    //build HTML

    $('#'+idcontainer).append(  '<div class="border '+idcontainer+'">'+
                                    '<div class="info">'+
                                        '<span class="value">'+objJSON.value+
                                        '</span>'+
                                        '<span class="title"><br/>'+objJSON.title+
                                        '</span>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="inner">'+
                                        '<div class="spinner pie"></div>'+
                                        '<div class="filler pie"></div>'+
                                        '<div class="mask"></div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>');
```

Comment: Show your HTML. It's best if you make a runnable example right here in your question that demontrates the issue (use the code snippet feature of the editor).

Comment: `of (default: null)
Type: Selector or Element or jQuery or Event
Which element to position against. If you provide a selector or jQuery object, the first matching element will be used. If you provide an event object, the pageX and pageY properties will be used. Example: "#top-menu"` > http://api.jqueryui.com/position/. You provide a simple string as parameter. It should be `of: parent` without any quotes or the relevant selector.

Comment: @Nico O Thats not working neither 
Editing in a sec

Comment: Please post your html. Wild guess is `idcontainer` holding the id of the object or (confusingly) it's class name? If It's the Id, use `$('#'+idcontainer)`.

Comment: Posted more code. idcontainer its just the name, without any selector character

Comment: It's just getting a variable inside "of:" don't complicate yourselves (please don't abandon me :( ... )

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because from what you posted, we don't see when `GravityCircle.position()` is called. The problem might be because `GravityCircle.position()` is called before the new element is created. From what I understand, it should be called everytime `GravityCircle.createGravityCircle()` is called.